# VideoView acting weird on scroll

Tags: android-linearlayout, android-videoview, border, viewgroup

I'm having a ViewGroup where I can scroll through per page, these pages are images.
Some have links, some have media on them, when there's for example a video square on the image I place a VideoView on it so when the user taps it, it plays the movie from the raw folder.

However, when I do this, and I scroll through to the next page or back, there's a black border over the next or previous screen, it's acting all messed up. Anyone has any idea what this is and how to fix this? Is it the VideoView it's behavior? Or is it my pager class or my other layout code??

piece of code:

```
                        LinearLayout linVid2 = new LinearLayout(this);
                    LinearLayout linVid = new LinearLayout(this);

                    linVid.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.landscape_1003_1_full);
                    linVid.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            1024, 748));

                    linVid2.setPadding(386, 53, 1024 - 587 - 386,
                            748 - 440 - 53);
                    linVid.addView(linVid2);

                    VideoView vd = new VideoView(this);
                    String tmp = MovieLink2.replace(".mp4", "");
                    int movieID = res.getIdentifier(tmp, "raw",
                            getPackageName());
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                            + getPackageName() + "/" + movieID);
                    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
                    vd.setMediaController(mc);
                    vd.setVideoURI(uri);
                    linVid2.addView(vd);
                    horizontalViewSwitcher.addView(linVid, current);
                    vd.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `requestLayout()` in the `onScrollChanged()` function. It resolved the same issue for me.